# Google Earth Imagery Updates Question

Tags: google-earth

How often does Google update their Monthly Google Earth Imagery Updates ?
https://mapsengine.google.com/10446176163891957399-16022013078000482234-4/mapview/?authuser=0

I see that it is dated last May 2015 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know (and I could be mistaken) there is no exact date or period of days that google waits to release their Monthly Imagery Updates.  Different parts of the world are constantly being updated and you can see the areas with new imagery here: https://mapsengine.google.com/10446176163891957399-04749531680953568577-4/mapview/?authuser=0 .  Also just because an area has had recent images taken doesnt not necessarily mean those images will be the ones being used on the site.  Some areas may have been updated recently, but those areas were covered with clouds etc... and the images were not used.

Comment: @ ed hankins I got this from somewhere but how or where do I find the link to their site ?

Comment: Let me go through my bookmarks and see if I can locate where I grabbed that information from.  I did find this link to show you what the newest imagery for your area is. https://followyourworld.appspot.com/   some other information I found is here: http://www.tech-faq.com/how-often-is-google-earth-updated.html , https://www.quora.com/How-often-is-Google-Street-View-updated , http://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2010/10/how_often_does_google_update_the_im.html , https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/rWQ1SD32Bm8